# how to use ecdsa and ecdh with only one keypair (p256)

Tags: go, rust, ecdsa, ecdh, ed25519

I need to create a keypair in Rust based on the p256 curve, because the publickey should be sent to another service which is implemented in Go, where the curve p256 is used.

In the Go version I am using crypto/ecdsa to generate the keypair. and then I can use that key to do both the signing and generation of keypairs.

I tried looking at different libraries for elliptic curve crypto in Rust, and I found a lot. I am especially interested in the -dalek libraries because they are pure Rust and I need to use this in WASM applications.

However if I use the x25519-dalek library then I am not getting the p256 curve which is used in Go neither am I getting signing functionality.

I would be open to change the curve used in Go to ed25519 but I can only find out how to use ed25519 for signing in Go.

I can't really find any resources anywhere about how to use ecdsa and ecdh with only one keypair.